# How to pass Command to program open in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, scripting, jboss

I am writing a shell script to auto-deploy a program with Jboss-cli, in linux ubuntu. I need to open the jboss cli interface and execute some commands but I want to do this automatically. 
what it looks like

```
cd /opt/jboss/bin
./jboss-cli.sh --connect
```

the above line open the jboss command line. I would like to be able to send a command to the open program like:
`undeploy FlcErp.ear`

I've tried to echo it and give it straight text but nothing will execute until the Jboss program is done running.

I've also tried `./jboss-cli.sh --connect undeploy "FlcErp.ear"` but It reads `"FlcErp.ear"` as a command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `jboss-cli.sh` reads from standard input, you can pipe the command to it:

```
echo 'undeploy FlcErp.ear' | ./jboss-cli.sh --connect
```

To execute multiple commands, you can use multiple `echo` commands.

```
{ echo 'undeploy FlcErp.ear'; echo 'other gommands'; echo 'go here'; } | ./jboss-cli.sh --connect
```

but a here-doc is usually easier:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect <<EOF
undeploy FlcErp.ear
other commands
go here
EOF
```

Comment: @Barmar Can you expand this answer so that first example is written for multiple commands?

Comment: @71GA Updated the answer